# Returning from a signal handler and leaving signal masked

Tags: c, synchronization, posix, signals, atomic

I've got a situation where a signal handler needs to, under certain conditions, return *without unmasking itself*, i.e. after returning the signal should remain blocked in the thread's signal mask. Jumping out of the signal handler with `longjmp` will not work because I need to return to the exact point that was interrupted like a normal signal handler return. Is there any conformant way to do this, short of using the `ucontext_t` which was removed from the standards? I cannot change signal handlers or dispositions; all effects must be local to the thread.

The purpose of this code has to do with some atomic operations and potential for a race condition or deadlock. Basically the potentially interrupted code looks like:

```
atomic_write(&thread_local_flag, 1);
atomic_dec(&global_counter);
```

If the flag has been set and the counter decremented, all is well and the signal handler has nothing to do, but the signal could possibly arrive between the two instructions. In this case, the signal handler wants to immediately return and let the decrement proceed, but the process is being bombarded with signals (intended to be received by all threads for an arcane synchronization purpose) and there's a possibility it could loop forever (or at least for unbounded time) processing signals while other threads never receive their signals.

If I could leave the signal blocked when the signal handler returns, there would be no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, the best I've found so far.. This seems to work and does not depend on any `ucontext` functions, just the structure which was not removed. In the signal handler:

```
if (thread_local_flag) {
    sigaddset(&((ucontext_t *)ctx)->uc_sigmask, sig);
    return;
}
```

Here `sig` and `ctx` are the first and third argument to the `SA_SIGINFO`-type signal handler, respectively.

Any thoughts on whether this is correct usage or a horrible hack (or both)?